# How to download and use excel with (CC BY4) authentication inside Python

Tags: python, data-science

I need to download and use an excel file directly inside the jupyter notebook from the new [Global Carbon Budget](https://data.icos-cp.eu/objects/1umMtgeUlhS2Y1YW_Qp94bu3) 
I tried many codes but without a hope. The only way was to get the file manually which is not an option for scientific and transparent code-review. To download the file in the browser you need to check and accept the (Creative Commons Attribution 4.0 international licence). Such "check" and redirection is not working in Python.
Any suggestion?

Ps. I tried (requests, BeautifulSoup, urllib2, and panda) packages but without a result. See the example

```
df= pd.read_excel('https://data.icos-cp.eu/objects/1umMtgeUlhS2Y1YW_Qp94bu3')
```

Answer (score 0):

> "The only way was to get the file manually which is not an option for scientific and transparent code-review. "

That isn't true according to the 'ICOS Carbon Portal Python Library':

> "This library provides easy access to data hosted at the ICOS Carbon Portal (https://data.icos-cp.eu/). By using this library you can load data files directly into memory. The approach of this library is to free you from downloading and maintaining a local copy of data files and if you choose to use our Jupyter Hub services, you don't even need computational power." - SOURCE: https://icos-carbon-portal.github.io/pylib/

It looks according to [here](https://icos-carbon-portal.github.io/pylib/modules/) like you could run the following in Jupyter for your case:

```py
%pip install icoscp
from icoscp.cpb.dobj import Dobj
myDobj = Dobj('1umMtgeUlhS2Y1YW_Qp94bu3')
```

Ideally the `%pip install` command would be in a different cell and you'd restart the kernel after running it.

**Then you need to set up authentication before running the next two lines that I listed above**. According to [here](https://icos-carbon-portal.github.io/pylib/modules/#authentication) you can use the `cpauth` module to authenticate.

Probably checking the other [Examples](https://icos-carbon-portal.github.io/pylib/examples/) would be advisable, too.

Comment: Thank you Wayne for your help. I tried to run the code but it doesn't work on that file. I got an error `[KeyError: 'columns']` Your answer helped me because I didn’t know before that they have their own Python Package.

Comment: Sure. I’ll try to get in touch with them. I emailed them yesterday. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with indirect solution using this code

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import numpy as np
url = "https://data.icos-cp.eu/licence_accept?ids=%5B%221umMtgeUlhS2Y1YW_Qp94bu3%22%5D"  
filename = "Globalcarbon.xlsx"  

response = requests.get(url)
#response.status_code=200 means its sucessful. It is a standard used in http codes. More explaination via https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/200
if response.status_code == 200:
    with open(filename, "wb") as f:
        f.write(response.content)
    print(excel_file.sheet_names)
    excel_file = pd.ExcelFile(filename)
    sheet_name = "Global Carbon Budget"
    df = pd.read_excel(filename, skiprows=range(20),sheet_name=sheet_name)
    df.fillna(value=np.nan, inplace=True)
    print(df.head(),df.tail(5)) 
else:
    print("Failed to download", url)
```

Comment: That's good. However, since they set up a way for nice citizens of the internet to access the data programmatically with authentication, it may be better to contact them and explain how they could improve things in the documentation of the 'ICOS Carbon Portal Python Library' tool. Working with you on your example failing may help them see how others could miss things.